# after upgrading to kernel 5.3 screen flickering started Refresh rate in 60.01 Hz

Tags: graphics, display, intel

I am new ubuntu user. My display card was not working intel graphics UHD. I installed kernel 5.3. Now display card is recognised but lot of flickering. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that only Google chrome was having flickering problem after upgrading to kernel 5.3. I disabled settings in Google chrome  "use hardware acceleration when available" under settings ->advanced settings>system. Now it is working fine.